# What is meaning of following xcode warning and how to resolve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, warnings

Warning is :

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:': 'void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void)' vs 'void (^__strong _Nonnull)()'

[image: This is a screenshot from xcode]

Can someone please help me understand and resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: which Xcode version you use?

Comment: Is this an Objective-C++ file? Do you perhaps have a mix of Objective-C and Objective-C++? What does the corresponding `@interface` look like? (Guess that motivates the question: the use of `()` somewhere, probably in the interface, which in C++ means `(void)` but in C means `(accept anything)`).

Comment: this code is in Objective C and I am using xcode 9.